# Circle with 4 clickable regions without overhang

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, geometry

As you see, I need a way to click in every "corner" of a circle, but it musn't be able to be clicked outside of the circle. I tried div, img and even draw it with canvas('es).
But nothing worked, so I'm here and ask you.

Comment: [Didn't try very hard](http://jsfiddle.net/b54zj/), did you? :p

Comment: It took me 3 minutes XD

Comment: Tell me your Answer, please!

Comment: Thanks bro, i messed my code up ^^